# What's the best way to include files in my classes? What I'm doing breaks frequently

Tags: php, oop

So I'm having some trouble with classes not finding the subclasses or parents sometimes.

For instance, I have a very simple class with a subclass that gives me a lot of trouble.

The main class is called Activities and the subclass is called DirectMessage.

Here's the activity class layout.

```
namespace activities;
require_once(INCLUDES . '/classes/activities/DirectMessage.php');

class activities extends \BaseController {
}
```

And here's the one for DirectMessage.

```
namespace DirectMessage;


use activities\activities;

class DirectMessage extends activities
{
}
```

I use activities all the time, but when I started including DirectMessage, it started giving me errors like this: `Fatal error: Class 'activities\activities' not found in /includes/classes/activities/DirectMessage.php on line 13`

Unfortunately, it doesn't ALWAYS give me this error, so it's got something to do with where it's being called from I guess.

Is there a better way to `require` my subclasses?

Comment: Yes, use proper autoloading

Comment: Care to explain that a little better?

Comment: Well, the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) explains this and there are many [already programmed scripts](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/). Do you have any additional questions?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [Composer's PSR-4 autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) for this, even if you're not loading in any dependencies with Composer. It's the easiest way I've found get basic autoloading working.

In short, PSR-4 autoloading will allow you to map namespaces to folder structures. Composer will generate an autoload file (`vendor/autoload.php`) - and this will be the one and only file you should have to `require()` in your entire project.